# Summing select values in column B if they match a given category in Column A

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column A is comprised of categories. Column B is comprised of values. I want excel to determine what rows in Column A match a given category and then sum values in Column B that correspond to those rows.

Say in Column A the wanted category are in row 2, 4, and 6. I  need to sum rows 2,4,6 only in Column B.

`=IF(A1:A10 = category_value)` return an ordered list of True/False statements. If True, that means that the row corresponding to the index of this ordered list matches the category_value.

`=IF(A1:A10 = category_value, ROW(A1:A10, "")` return the row numbers for the True values in the aforementioned list and removes all False

Now, I need to elect the returned rows in Column B. I suppose the `INDEX` function might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

The `sumif` function will do the trick:

```
=SUMIF($A1:$A10, "some category", $B1:B10)
```

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't. Say in Column A the wanted categories are in row 2, 4, and 6. I  need to sum rows 2,4,6 from Column B.

Comment: @oolveea that's what `countif` does. If this isn't what you're looking for, can you edit your post and share some sample data with the result you're expecting?

Comment: I solved the problem but the moderator deleted it…